# Return file from MVC action with using statements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stream, .net-4.5

To return a file from an action, you do:

```
return File(myStream, ...);
```

This means you can't wrap `myStream` in a using statement, which makes me sad. Suppose I had multiple things in using statements in order to get to the meat of the file I wanted to return. For instance, I am returning a file from the database which is stored as a SQL Filestream:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = ...)
{
    using (SqlTransaction trans = ...)
    {
        using (SqlFileStream fileStream = ...)
        {
            return File(fileStream, ...);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do this within using statements to ensure that the stream, transaction and connection are all closed after the file is streamed. I can't do that, of course, because as soon as the return statement is execute, all of the things I'm using are closed. I do realize that the stream I send to `File(...)` will be closed, but the other things will remain open (in theory).

My solution is this:

```
SqlConnection connection = ...;
SqlTransaction trans = ...;
SqlFileStream fileStream = ...;

return new DisposableFileStreamResult(fileStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file.Name), file.Name, () =>
{
    fileStream.Dispose();  //It's already disposed but for clarity...
    trans.Dispose();
    connection.Dispose();
});
```

DisposableFileStreamResult looks like:

```
public class DisposableFileStreamResult : FileStreamResult
{
    public Action Cleanup { get; set; }

    public DisposableFileStreamResult(Stream stream, string contentType) : this(stream, contentType, null) { }

    public DisposableFileStreamResult(Stream stream, string contentType, string fileDownloadName) : this(stream, contentType, fileDownloadName, null) { }

    public DisposableFileStreamResult(Stream stream, string contentType, string fileDownloadName, Action cleanup)
        : base(stream, contentType)
    {
        base.FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;
        this.Cleanup = cleanup;
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        base.WriteFile(response);

        if (this.Cleanup != null)
            this.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

I don't want to read a bunch of stuff into memory; I don't like byte arrays! Is there any built-in way to do this using MVC4? What if I have to return a large file? Is my temporary solution a reasonable one or is it overkill or not necessary?